# Supply input immediately to command and get exit code

Tags: ruby

With python I can do `proc.communicate(lines)` to a command process and "lines" is available instantly as soon as the program starts.

So now I'm trying to do the same with ruby using Open3:

```rb
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
stdin.puts(lines)
```

The problem is that there's a slight delay between when the program starts, and when the stdin gets supplied, that delay does not exist in the python version.

How can I run a command, inject stdin, process stdin instantly/at-start, and receive the exitcode (wait_thr in this case) ?

Comment: Could it be that `stdin` is buffered? What happens if you set it to unbuffered?

Comment: Hi @user1934428, how would you make it unbuffered?

Comment: The class`IO` has a `sync=` method: https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-sync

Comment: @user1934428 I tried (right before the "puts" line) to set stdin.sync = false and stdin.sync = true, both look the same, still the slight delay.

Comment: Well, `false` does not make sense here, but if `true` does not work, we have to look for something else. How do you notice, that there is a delay? I.e. how does `cmd` communicate to you the time when it received the input?

Comment: The issue was with the command itself. Some variation of it makes it load instantly, another has the delay. It was not a ruby issue. Sorry & thanks.